# Node.Js, JSON Parse Error, Unexpected End of Input

Tags: json, node.js

Problem Solved!!

---

So I have been following this mini-guide found [here](http://greenido.wordpress.com/2013/08/21/yahoo-finance-api-with-nodejs/).

I have inserted the code below for ease of access. However when I run the code (after inputting proper details for google) I get an error at the end.

```
Logging into Google...
Logged into Google
Searching for Worksheet 'S'...

JSON Parse Error: SyntaxError: Unexpected end of input
```

---

Any idea what I am doing wrong? Is there some change I need to make? Also in the interest of learning, if you could also explain how you solved my problem and not just give me the solution so that I can solve similar problems in the future by myself.

Thanks

Uk

```
/**
* Fetch data from the web and save it into a Google Sheet document
*
* Requirements:
  1. NodeJS
  2. npm install request
  3. npm install cheerio
  4. npm install edit-google-spreadsheet

* Author: Ido Green | plus.google.com/+Greenido
* Date: 15 Aug 2013
*/

var request     = require('request');
var cheerio     = require('cheerio');
var Spreadsheet = require('edit-google-spreadsheet');

// Some parameters 
// TODO: move from the global scope
var ticker  = "LVS";
var yUrl    = "http://finance.yahoo.com/q/ks?s=" + ticker;
var financeDetails = new Array();
var keyStr         = new Array();


// Upload our data to G-Sheet
function sheetReady(err, spreadsheet) {
    if (err) throw err;
    spreadsheet.add({ 1: { 1: "Attribute" } });
    spreadsheet.add({ 1: { 2: "Value" } });

    spreadsheet.add({ 
      2: {
        1: keyStr
      }
    });
    spreadsheet.add({ 
      2: {
        2: financeDetails
      }
    });

    spreadsheet.send(function(err) {
      if(err) throw err;
      console.log("Updated " + financeDetails.length + " Items with data");
    });
  }

//
// The main call to fetch the data, parse it and work on it.  
//
request(yUrl, function (error, response, body) {
  if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
    var $ = cheerio.load(body);

    // the keys - We get them from a certain class attribute
    var td = $('.yfnc_tablehead1');
    $(td).each(function(j, val) {
      keyStr[j] = $(val).text();
    });

    // the values
    // TODO: normalize them 
    var tData = $('.yfnc_tabledata1');
    $(tData).each(function(j, val) {
      financeDetails[j] = $(val).text();
    });

    // Let's do something with the data we have
    for (var i=0; i < financeDetails.length; i++) {
      console.log (i + ") " + keyStr[i] + " " + financeDetails[i]);
    }

    // upload our data to Google sheet
    // yFinanceDataPerComapy
    Spreadsheet.create({
      debug: true,
      username: 'TODO-fill',
      password: 'TODO-fill',
      debug: true,
      spreadsheetName: 'TODO-yourSheetName',
      worksheetName: 'TODO-Sheet1orAbetterName',
      callback: sheetReady
    });
  }

}); // -- end of request --
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an error with the edit-google-spreadsheet module reported [here](https://github.com/jpillora/node-edit-google-spreadsheet/issues/29). The error is thrown when trying to retrieve private spreadsheets. There are a few options you can take.

- Make the spreadsheet public.
- Try to use the [*fixed* pull request](https://github.com/Pingflow/node-edit-google-spreadsheet/tree/pr-response-format). It looks like there are still issues that need to be resolved.
- Use the worksheet id instead of the worksheet name. This is a more difficult process:

  1. Start by opening your spreadsheet in google drive
  2. Find the spreadsheet id in the url. Example:

     ```
     https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/SPREADSHEET_ID_HERE/edit?usp=drive_web
     ```
  3. List the sources by going to this url:

     ```
     view-source:https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds/worksheets/SPREADSHEET_ID_HERE/private/full
     ```
  4. Find the entry from the response (od6 in the below example):

```
<entry>
    <id>https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds/worksheets/SPREADSHEET_ID_HERE/private/full/od6</id>
    ...
    <title type='text'>Sheet1</title>
    ...
</entry>
```